# with torch.no_grad: AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

```
with torch.no_grad:AttributeError: __enter__
```

I got this error while running pytorch code.

I have torch==0.4.1 torchvision==0.3.0, I run the code in google colab.

Answer (score 10):

`torch.no_grad` is a contextmanager it really has `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

You should use it with `with` statement, like this

```
with context_manager():
    pass
```

Thus, simply replace `with torch.no_grad:` (accessing the attribute) with `with torch.no_grad():` (calling a method) to use contextmanager properly.

Comment: Thanks for your support :) I have encountered with another error: **RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors does not require grad** Do you have any idea??

Comment: @DayanandDhumala I am not familiar with your computational graph, but try to set `requires_grad=True` for that tensor when creating tensor, e.g. `my_tensor = torch.tensor([1], requires_grad=True)` or `my_tensor.requires_grad = True`

Comment: Hallo @trsvchn: